# How to use LIMIT in PostgreSQL correctly to only query one row per ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, where-clause

I have a query where users enter a list of stocks called `{placeholders}`, that is stored in a python variable. The query will pull 9 columns from `t1`, and 1 column from `t2`.

```
f''' SELECT t1.id, cast(t1.enterprisevalue as money), ROUND(t1.enterprise_value_revenue, 2),
      ROUND(t1.revenuepershare, 2), 
      ROUND(t1.debt_to_equity, 2), 
      ROUND(t1.profitmargin, 2), 
      ROUND(t1.price_to_sales, 2), 
      ROUND(t1.price_to_book, 2), 
      ROUND(t1.put_call_ratio, 2), 
      t2.employees, 
      cast(ROUND(t1.revenue_per_employee, 2) as money)
FROM 
      security_advanced_stats as t1 
LEFT JOIN security_stats as t2 USING (id)
WHERE id IN ({placeholders})
ORDER by id LIMIT 1;
'''
```

I want ONE row per Stock symbol in `{placeholders}`, which is why I'm using the LIMIT here. However, the syntax is wrong and the query is now limiting `{placeholders}` to only the first symbol in the list. The output of my query is only showing data for one stock symbol, and not the others in `{placeholders`}

If I take away the `LIMIT` command, then I get all of the rows in the database, when I'm only looking for the most recent record for my stocks (Which I label as `id`).

This is what happens when I take out limit, Notice there are two symbols EXPD and VFC, but they each all other entries with the same data.
[image]

I only want the most recent row for EXPD and VFC in the case above.

How can I fix my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DISTINCT ON` feature is very well suited for this. Basically, you can choose the fields which you don't want duplicated, and only get the first row per your sorting.
(I'm assuming you have some kind of `timestamp` column, so we can get the most recent row for each ID.)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1.id)
    t1.id, 
    cast(t1.enterprisevalue as money), 
    ROUND(t1.enterprise_value_revenue, 2),
    ROUND(t1.revenuepershare, 2), 
    ROUND(t1.debt_to_equity, 2), 
    ROUND(t1.profitmargin, 2), 
    ROUND(t1.price_to_sales, 2), 
    ROUND(t1.price_to_book, 2), 
    ROUND(t1.put_call_ratio, 2), 
    t2.employees, 
    cast(ROUND(t1.revenue_per_employee, 2) as money)
FROM security_advanced_stats as t1 
LEFT JOIN security_stats as t2 USING (id)
WHERE id IN ({placeholders})
ORDER by id, timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you so much. FYI I didn't end up using the timestamp DESC.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! But keep in mind that if you don't specify a second ORDER BY column, the single row you get per ID won't necessarily be the most recent row for that ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first_value` with `group by`:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
    cast(first_value(t1.enterprisevalue as money) over w), 
    round(first_value(t1.enterprise_value_revenue) over w, 2),
    ...
from security_advanced_stats as t1 
left join security_stats as t2 USING (id)
where id in ({placeholders})
group by t1.id
window w as (partition by t1.id);
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, compared to @Blue Star's comment, this would looks like it is more computationally costy?

Comment: @Dre I'm not sure, maybe they are optimized to the same plan, but no problem, I'd go for their solution as well;)

Comment: Thanks for the edits and your comment though, I always like knowing multiple solutions to problems. Thumbs up!